# Why isn't my sheet attached to the window it's run for?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller, cocoa-sheet

I have a NIB which contains two windows, one is the app's main window visible at launch and the other is a custom sheet (and therefore not visible at launch). When the sheet is required my controller calls:

`[NSApp beginSheet: sheetWindow modalForWindow: mainWindow modalDelegate: self didEndSelector: @selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo: nil];`

which displays the sheet window and starts a modal session, *but* the window has a standard Aqua title bar, is not 'connected' to the main window and can be moved around just like a regular window. Needless to say, this is not desirable :-). Why doesn't the sheet window "pop out" of the window it's run for, as sheets usually do when begun in this fashion?

I had wondered whether the fact that I was beginning the sheet inside the controller's `-awakeFromNib` might have an effect, so I moved the sheet to a button's action I could trigger later. This didn't change the behaviour. I haven't thought of anything else to try. I'm targeting the 10.5 SDK, using Xcode 3.1.

**Edit:** so it looks like I've created a modal dialog; sheets and app-modal dialogs are both started with the `-beginSheet:modalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:` method. But how do I indicate that my window should be a sheet and *not* a modal dialog?

Comment: Check that mainWindow is not nil.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong about it, maybe some context could help.

Comment: You should make that an answer, Nathan. It's almost certainly right.

Comment: I agree with Chuck :-). Nathan, answer that and I'll upvote and accept - thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, see Renaud Pradenc's answer below about the "Visible at launch" setting in the nib file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If mainWindow is nil then the sheet will be displayed as a window/dialog.

Answer (score 102):

This happened to me a couple of days ago:

- You forgot to set the *window* outlet of your window controller (*File's owner* of the Nib file).
  As Indicated by Nathan, you may see that the `-[NSWindowController window]` method returns nil.
- You must also uncheck the *Visible at launch* option of the sheet.

Comment: "Visible at launch" turned out to be my problem - the sheet appeared at the correct time, but disconnected from its window, and would not disappear despite my orderOut: call.  Thanks for posting this!

Comment: "Visible at launch" was indeed my problem, too. Very useful answer.

Comment: Visible at launch was my problem too!

Comment: Visable at launch... indeed it was my problem.

Comment: Another one for visibleAtLaunch. How very odd. In my case once the dialogue was closed and re-opened, it was attached to the correct window. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: Visible at launch was my problem too!

Comment: Yep. Visible at launch, still the solution on 10.9.2

Comment: Visible at launch is still the solution on 10.10.2.

Comment: My god, visible at launch. That couldn't have been any more obscure. For me, the issue was that the sheet would complain that it was being displayed twice. The sheet never appeared and the app would crash.

Comment: visible at launch :)