# Modal sheet is not attached to window

Tags: macos, swift, nsviewcontroller, nssplitview

I'm trying to call modal sheet inside my root window. I've have success with showing sheet but it **is not attached to main window**.

I've [read about similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671204/why-isnt-my-sheet-attached-to-the-window-its-run-for):

1. Window outlet is set (it is automaticly set by XCode)
2. Visible at launch option is unchecked.

My application has storyboard (image below), I'm calling sheet from Root Window Controller. I've tried to call sheet from Root Split View Controller but had no success.

```
let loginWindow = LoginWindowController(windowNibName: "LoginWindowController")

self.window?.beginSheet(loginWindow.window!, completionHandler: { (res) -> Void in
    print("completed")
})
```

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried to call *beginSheet* (also to display sheet you can use *presentViewControllerAsSheet* or *performSegueWithIdentifier*) within **viewDidLoad** method. That was the error.

You can call sheet only after view was appeared. Then sheet will be placed correctly, inside window and without window/view hierarchy errors.

Now I'm calling sheet in **viewDidAppear** method and everything is working